# How to make inner element with position:absolute override overflow:hidden of outer element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div id="outer" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="otherStuff">
      some other stuff goes in here
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="popup" style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want my `#popup` element to be overflow the `#outer` element, but now, it is just cut out by the `#outer` element. By the way, `#popup` element should be positioned based on `#wrapper` element rather than `#outer` element.

Comment: That is the thing about overflow property, once you specified that the overflowing content of the parent is hidden, it will be. Unless, you set `#popup` to `position: fixed`, then it relates to the root element (or I dare say to the window)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
```

make it impossible to be shown.

if it's popup, why it should be in the "overflow:hidden" div? or why wrapper should be relative?

you can do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/9FehL/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but overflow: hidden is just that. There is no chance ever that you have an element that is located inside of it (considering the dom-structure) that will visually be displayed outside the borders of this element. Popups are usually best placed in the root level, at first or last element inside the body element